# How to plot graph when interval and data is given

Tags: graph, analysis, gnuplot

Suppose i have obtained some data which is like this :-

Size-Range Percentage

[1-3]       2%
[3-8]       6%
[8-20]      10%
[20-50]     30%
[50-100]    80%
[100-200]   99.99%

Suppose i run an algorithm with many data files and i got this output.
1st column shows the time of algorithm and 2nd column shows the percentile of data processed.
I just want to plot this data.
I want to draw some graph.

Please suggest me how can i do this using gnuplot or any other tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a histogram or a barplot in R (more details about it [here](http://www.r-project.org/)). For a good tutorial in this direction, please see [Producing Simple Graphs with R](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/#barcharts).

For example, suppose you have the data in a CSV file which looks like this:

```
Lo,Hi,Percentage
1,3,2
3,8,6
...
100,200,99.99
```

Then, to load the CSV file in R you could write:

```
> dataSample <- read.csv(file="C:/sample.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Note that on *NIX machines you should replace the path to your file with something like "/home/username/path/to/sample.csv". To check the values, simply type:

```
> dataSample
```

From here, you can use the data to plot your graphs like in the tutorial.